# fatal error: QCoreApplication: No such file or directory, using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm new to QT.

I created the code in QT Application with support of QMake,
then I migrated the code in a CMake compatible application.

Since then I'm getting QCoreApplication no such file/directory error.

It also gives following message:

> 23:03:11: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2. Error while
>   building/deploying project HCIServer (kit: CMake-New-Kit) The kit
>   CMake-New-Kit has configuration issues which might be the root cause
>   for this problem. When executing step "Make"

---

Kit Configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Compiler: g++
- QT Version: 5.8.0

Comment: show CMakeLists.txt please.

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


project(HCIServer)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp"
    "mouseevent.cpp"
    "udpserver.cpp"
    )



Adding the find_package(Qt5Widgets) is giving another error like Configuration incomplete, errors occured!

Answer (score 1):

your CMake configuration is wrong.

This is a really small configuration file for CMake based projects:

```
project(HCIServer)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp mouseevent.cpp udpserver.cpp)
target_link_librarieS(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

without the find_package, CMake doesn't knows where to look for Qt, and whithout target_link_libraries, CMake doens't know what your application needs.